# Upgrading from iPad 1 to iPad Air - restoring individual app data?

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm hoping that a jolly fat bearded mythical character will deliver me an iPad Air in a weeks time :) I currently have an original iPad 1, stuck back on iOS 5.

It's been jailbroken, but I don't honestly think I'll miss any of the jailbroken apps. Although I know that I can restore a backup from the old iPad to the Air, will this have any negative effects - especially as I'll be going from jailbroken to non-jailbroken and iOS 5 to iOS 7? I'd like to keep the Air as "clean" as possible, and avoid dragging over a ton of legacy crap that I don't need.

Ideally, I'd like to just restore selective apps and their data to the new iPad - of course, apps can be re-downloaded, but is there any way (with 3rd party software) to selectively restore individual app data to an iOS 7 device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can backup data from apps with a program such as [**PhoneView**](https://ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) (Mac) or [**iFunBox**](http://www.i-funbox.com/) (Mac & Windows), and restore the data individually per app.

> Browse, manage and download most any data saved by App Store apps from your iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch. If you're looking for a quick way to download saved recordings, videos or images from your apps, this is it. Even transfer game high scores between devices. *— PhoneView*

Open the app in PhoneView or iFunBox, and copy the folders out, then copy them to your new device.

Comment: Thanks - iFunBox looks like the app for me. It's not _quite_ as easy as I'd like - it would be great to be able to back up/restore an app with personal data with a single click - but it definitely does the job.